# Meaning of array in wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

So I am working with wordpress and using the following code I get the following. I know this must be a basic question but I want to know what it means:

`[1012] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) 
[1013] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) 
[1014] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) 
[1018] => Array ( [0] => 0 )`

PHP:

```
<?php
 $all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id());
 print_r( $all_meta_for_user );
?>
```

Comment: It will give all details of the current user. Read `Get all meta data` on function [reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) page.

Comment: yes thanks..but i want to know what this means [1012] => Array ( [0] => 1 )

Comment: This is probably information that some plugin is storing for the user.

Comment: Ok thanks.. then how do i just display that information that has value   Array ( [0] => 1 ) and not something else  e.g Array ( [0] => 0).

Comment: Ok. Two things here: first of all, I'll store all that data together inside a single key and I'll remove the uneeded single-element array: `[my_plugin] => Array( [1012] => 1, [1013] => 0 ...)`. That lowers the possibility of your data mixing with other's plugin data, having conflicts, etc. When you have that, it's only a matter of accessing the value like this: `if ($all_meta_for_user['my_plugin'][$id] == 1) do_something()` where `$id` refers to the information you want to check.

Answer (score 2):

This data is user's metadata https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

As you say, this is your metadata. Two things here: first of all, I'll store all that data together inside a single key and I'll remove the uneeded single-element array:

`[my_plugin] => Array( [1012] => 1, [1013] => 0 ...)`

That lowers the possibility of your data mixing with other's plugin data, having conflicts, etc. Also, as second array is probably not needed, it will make access to it a little simpler.

When you have that, it's only a matter of accessing the value like this:

`if ($all_meta_for_user['my_plugin'][$id] == 1) show_the_post()`

where $id is the post ID.

To use a single key, I'll do something like this (untested):

`$posts_meta_for_user = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'my_plugin', true);
if (is_array($posts_meta_for_user)) {
  $posts_meta_for_user[$new_id] = $new_value;
  update_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'my_plugin', $posts_meta_for_user);
} else {
  $posts_meta_for_user = array($new_id => $new_value);
  add_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'my_plugin', $awesome_level);
}`

Notice that we get only the meta value named 'my_plugin' and test it already had a value by checking that is an array. If it is, we update it, and if it's not, we create a new one. `$new_id` is the post ID you want to store and `$new_value` the value.

Comment: Yes I have a custom code, that produces this metadata.  [1012] is the id of the post

Comment: @xavier.. thanks.. how can i store all that data in a single key?